# Avoid global variable when creating object

Tags: python, object

How can I avoid a global variable when creating an object? Someone told me that when I create the objects, it is considered doing that globally.

For instance if I have my class like this

```
 class Windpower(object):
def __init__(self,name):
    self.name=name

def calc_area(self,dia):
    area=((dia/2)**2*math.pi) 
    return area

def calc_wind_energy(self,area,v):
    energy=(random.uniform(0.10,0.4)*1.2*area*v**3*0.5) 
    return energy

def get_velocity(self): 
    with open('smhi.txt') as input:
        smhi_list=[int(line.strip()) for line in input if line.strip()] 
        return smhi_list

windpower = Windpower("Stockholm") 
solarpower=Solarpower(500,4)
```

Main.py

```
def average(lat):
    energy_list = [] #
    table = [] # 
    area = klass.solarpower.area
    sundigit=klass.solarpower.sundigit
```

Comment: What do you mean by "avoid a global variable"?

Comment: @KSFT I was told that I cant iniate a object like that

Comment: And that I could be considered as a global

Comment: Like what? [extra chars]

Comment: What do you mean by "I could be considered as a global"?

Comment: So you don't see any problem doing that @KSFT?? Can I create a object in the main program though???

Comment: One question mark is fine. I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @Pellegrino I think you might be referring to the instantiation of your objects on the module level, which can be executed on module import.  It might be better to place more code in the question so we could have a context.

Comment: @Meitham could we chat? Someone told me that I could create the object after def average(lat) which is in the main program

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an anti-pattern in python than anything else.  The act of having executable code on the module level should be avoided, because this can be executed when the module is being imported by other modules.

There are however cases to place code on the module level, such as providing objects on the module as part of your API (think Singleton), or doing any module initialization.

If you need this code to be executed only when you run the module as the main program you should place them under

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    windpower = Windpower("Stockholm") 
    solarpower=Solarpower(500,4)
```

Or put them in a function.

Bear in mind that the term "global" is incorrect here, as these objects are scoped within the module they're defined in, rather than the whole executable program.

Comment: it still doesn't work i tried that earlier. It says that module object has no attribute when I run from main

Comment: Do you have any solution?? @Meitham

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate your objects in the top level of the module (a python file), as you do in the example code you gave, they're accessible from the root of the module.

However, you really should instantiate them in the module where you use them. Here's an example:

wind.py

```
class WindPower(object):
  def __init__(self,name):
    self.name=name
```

main.py

```
import wind
city = wind.WindPower("Stockholm")

velocity = city.get_velocity()
```